# Clear WebBrowser control browsing history

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, browser-history

I want to clear WebBrowser control history after WebBrowser completes its browsing.

Comment: What history are you trying to clear?  Your visitors?  If so, I am fairly sure that is not possible.  If you are trying to clear your own, why not just use private browsing (available int FF, Chrome, and Safari - not sure about IE).

Comment: i have created simple webbrowsing application in visual studio c#/.net. I want to clear the history of my application whwn i will browse using my application the browsing history will take space so i want to clear it after browsing

Comment: How you would do that depends on how you implemented the HTML display. Are you using an embedded IE control or something?

Comment: It is difficult to see what is being asked here. Are you talking about removing the navigation log in the webbrowser control via ITravelLogStg, removing a URL from the global url history via IUrlHistoryStg, or removing files from the WinInet cache via DeleteUrlCacheEntry?

Answer (score 1):

The history state of the `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowse` control is internal and cannot be modified directly. All actions are performed via the `GoBack` and `GoForward` methods.

You can prevent your users from going backwards and forwards by setting the `CanGoBack` and `CanGoForward` properties to false. You would also want to modify the `AllowWebBrowserDrop`, `WebBrowserShortcutsEnabled` and `IsWebBroserContextMenuEnabled` properties as well.

Because history is only exposed through these methods, properties and user actions there is no need to clear the internal history state because the user cannot act on it. Note that session history (i.e. the back/forward buttons) is a separate concept from the "browser history" (what you see in the History panel in IE).

Note that it's possible that WebBrowser instances contained within other programs may write to the Windows user IE history files, however I don't know for certain. If they do I doubt there's anything you can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are two types of history. One is "Visited" pages list, and the other is the actual history you see in IE's history user interface.

If you want to remove the visited pages list, you need to use DeleteUrlCacheEntry to delete each item. By looping through using FindFirst/NextUrlCacheEntry API's you can get access to the time and date these items were creates, and therefore only delete the items created after your browser session started and before it was finished.

For FindFirst/NextUrlCacheEntry and DeleteUrlCacheEntry information, there are pre-written codes online that you can use, and then it will be easy for you to create a filter to decide which items you want deleted when you are looping through these cache entries.

Let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Comment: Hiya @Erx Can you provide some actual code for this? Maybe a URL?